# Are there any fax sending applications?

Tags: software-recommendation, fax

Are there any fax sending application written for ubuntu. If yes how can I configure and install on ubuntu 64 bit machine.

Uname -a

> Linux XXXXX 2.6.38-11-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 12 21:17:25 UTC
>   2011 x86_64 x86_64       x86_64 GNU/Linux

### Updates:

I found couple of them,

1. hylafax-client
2. mgetty-fax

Comment: Do you have a fax modem and a phone line?  E.g. a Class 1, Class 2, or class 2.0 fax modem?  Or are you looking for something that would use VOIP (FOIP)?  Or perhaps a web service like metrofax?

Comment: This might partly answer your question: The article "How to send faxes directly from within LibreOffice?" explains in detail about print to fax, updated and is proven to work. You should give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Searching `fax` in the software center I have found `kFax` and `gtk-eFax`, why aren't they good?

Comment: efax-gtk is very good.